# How to read XingHeaders and VBRIHeaders from MP3 files using TagLib-Sharp

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib-sharp

I need to extract the information stored in the Xing and Fraunhofer VBRI headers of MP3 files using TagLib-Sharp.

I've searched around the web for an example, looked at the source code, but it's not obvious how to use the XingHeader and VBRIHeader classes. They don't look to be part of the File/AudioFile properties for MPEG.

The constructor needs a ByteVector class which is defined in the TagLib namespace.

Can anybody provide an example of using the XingHeader and VBRIHeader classes? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
foreach(ICodec codec in file.Properties.Codecs) {
    Mpeg.AudioHeader header = (Mpeg.AudioHeader) codec;
    if(header == null)
        return;

    if(header.XingHeader != Mpeg.XingHeader.Unknown) {
        /* CODE HERE */
    }

    if(header.VBRIHeader != VBRIHeader.Unknown) {
        /* CODE HERE */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and get you back in a few days.

Comment: The comparaison with .Unknown doesn't work but there is a .IsPresent property which indicates if the header is present or not. This put me on the right track. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In fact, after checking that out further, the Xing implementation in TagLib doesn't fetch the different variables in the header, so I did that by myself. This page is a great reference for the LAME extensions in the Xing header: http://gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html It's not very hard to do, TagLib points you to the first frame of data, and you detect if it's a Xing frame and you fetch the encoder delay/padding which is needed for gapless MP3 playback. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: By the way, it seems that TagLib doesn't recognize the Xing header in CBR files. It seems to be because the CBR files have "Info" in the header instead of "Xing" (see gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html).  I've made a prototype which reads Xing/Info headers (Xing is for VBR and ABR files and Info for CBR files), and confirmed this. In short, TagLib has awesome support for tags, but it sucks for Xing/Info and VBRI headers.