# How to read XingHeaders, VBRIHeaders and sampleCount from MP3 files using TagLib-C++

Tags: c++, qt, audio, taglib

Is there a way to determine if an audio file has a variable bitrate, and extract the sampleCount() through the LibTag? I need to find out 'cause the Qt QMediaPlayer class incorrectly calculates audio files duration with variable bitrate, and the only way to correct is discover if the audio has a variable bit rate and divide the length for [sampleCount()](https://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1IT_1_1Properties.html#a645a7bf69a54cb42b15cf8ecf8aee0d6) duration.

Since the documentation TagLib is a bit confusing, I managed to create just the fileref

```
void MainWindow::playerOnMediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
{
if (status == QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia) {     
QString mediafile = playlist->currentMedia().canonicalUrl().toString();
TagLib::FileRef fr(reinterpret_cast<constwchar_t*>(mediafile.utf16()),true);
        //…
    }
}
```

But I don't know how do for discover if the audio has a variable bit rate and its sampleCount()

Yes, I know there is this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196011/how-to-read-xingheaders-and-vbriheaders-from-mp3-files-using-taglib-sharp), but is related to Sharp language

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to be working with a `TagLib::MPEG::File` to be able to access the `XingHeader`.  Here's an example:

```
static void printXingHeader(const char *fileName)
{
    TagLib::FileRef ref(fileName);
    TagLib::MPEG::File *file = dynamic_cast<TagLib::MPEG::File *>(ref.file());

    if(!file)
        return;

    TagLib::MPEG::Properties *properties = file->audioProperties();
    const TagLib::MPEG::XingHeader *xingHeader = properties->xingHeader();

    if(!xingHeader)
        return;

    std::cout << "total frames: " << xingHeader->totalFrames()
              << " total size: " << xingHeader->totalSize()
              << std::endl;

}
```